# AWK: match duplicate elements from two fields/columns or arrays

Tags: bash, unix, awk

I have this input:

```
hostname1 111.111.111.123 222.222.222.222
hostname2 123.123.123.123 132.132.132.132
hostname3 101.102.103.104 111.111.111.123
hostname4 192.168.100.123 192.168.101.123
```

How can I tell `awk` to match duplicate IP `111.111.111.123` (from 2nd field 1st row and 3rd field 3rd row?

As a first thought, I think I need to create arrays with all elements for `$2` and `$3`. But how do I cross-check them afterwards and identify duplicate elements?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to ONLY check for cross match, this will do

```
$ awk '{a[$2]; b[$3]; 
        if($2 in b) print "duplicate " $2; 
        if($3 in a) print "duplicate " $3}' file

duplicate 111.111.111.123
```

non uniqueness on the same column is not considered.

For another input file, for example

```
a 1 2
a 1 3
a 2 0
a 3 4
```

you'll only get

```
duplicate 2
duplicate 3
```

but not for `1`.

Comment: how? why do you think so?

Comment: Based on your answer I did both cross match and also same column match by using `for` loops in the END block. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following `awk` command:

```
awk '{a[$2]++;a[$3]++}END{for(i in a){if(a[i]>1){print i}}}' file
```

Explanation (as multiline version):

```
{
    # Count occurrences of 2nd and 3rd field in array 'a'
    a[$2]++
    a[$3]++
}
# Once the end of input has been reached
END {
    # Iterate through the array a
    for(i in a){
        # Print any IP which occurred more than one times
        if(a[i]>1){
            print i
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah I see, I was already doing `array1[$2]++` and `array2[$3]++` (for printing duplicate message regarding specific column), didn't know that I could use the same array name to populate with values from multiple fields (columns). If I am already doing the `array1` and `array2` thing, would it be possible to join them as well into the `a` array you gave as example?

Comment: I voted your answer as well because it also does what I needed but the accepted answer was better for my needs.